# How to populate phone number field into RingCentral (Click To Dial) layout using JavaScript

Tags: visualforce

I installed RingCentral Click To Dial package, I have a Visualforce page with no header. I'm displaying the RingCentral layout in quick action in my VF page.

My requirement is in my VF page when click on phone number I have to populate the clicked phone number field into the RingCentral "To:" field through JavaScript.

Is it possible. if not is there any way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The RingCentral for Salesforce package has integrated click-to-dial built-in now.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EORsjUAH

If you need more customization, you can use the RingCentral Embeddable Voice widget which is a customizable version of this:

https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-embeddable-voice

A Salesforce demo using Embeddable Voice is available here:

https://github.com/ringcentral-tutorials/ringcentral-web-widget-demos